# How does WordPress get the upgrade URL?

Tags: updates, upgrade, core, core-modifications

Can anyone point me to the location in the code where WordPress gets the core update url (eg: https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/en_AU/wordpress-4.8.2.zip)?

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the wordpress.org API version checker endpoint ([limited documentation here](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API#Version_Check)) and is retrieved in the [`wp_version_check()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_version_check/).